# Was it possible to connect 2 IDE drives to old laptop?

Tags: laptop

PATA/IDE allows two drives co-exist on single cable in a Master/Slave mode.
In old laptops, there was an IDE 44-pin port.

Assuming that IDE slave is not taken by a CDROM, is it possible (with some kind of cable splitter) to connect two IDE drives to that port? Will this configuration let the drives to be seen by BIOS?

Comment: Most standard IDE cables had two connectors for two drives.  Any old geek has a box full of them in his basement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the BIOS is hardcoded to only accept the CDROM on the IDE slave, it should work.

I'm using an old Lenovo laptop motherboard as a desktop motherboard and it can see 4 HDD as expected